# Fixed Menu doesn't work with current dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I have created this menu with a dropdown feature when you hover over "treatments". But when I apply the "position: fixed;" in the container class on CSS the dropdown menu doesn't function anymore. The menu goes to a fixed position but the dropdown feature won't function with the fixed position. I would like to solve it with CSS, any suggestions on how?

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.9);
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.container a {
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.container a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #ff008f;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.98);
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f9e9ff;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="UCL.css">

  <title>Home</title>

  <div class="stripes">

    <div class="container">
      <a href="contact-us.html" target="_top">Contact Us</a>
      <a href="products-gifts.html" target="_top">Products & 
Gifts</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Treatments</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="body-contouring.html" target="_top">Body 
Contouring</a>
          <a href="cellulite.html" target="_top">Cellulite</a>
          <a href="laser-hair-reduction.html" target="_top">Laser Hair Reduction</a>
          <a href="laser-peels.html" target="_top">Laser 
Peels</a>
          <a href="led.html" target="_top">LED</a>
          <a href="photofacial.html" target="_top>" Photofacial & Photobody</a>
            <a href="spider-veins.html" target="_top">Spider 
Veins</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="home.html" target="_top">Home</a>
    </div>

</head>
```

Comment: Unrelated to your specific issue, but there are a few problems with the HTML you provided: (1) You should never have any HTML content in the <head> - that's reserved for metadata (`meta` tags, `link` tags, `title` tag). Your content should be in the <body>. (2) You're missing a closing `</div>` at the end to close your `.stripes` container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the `overflow: hidden` on your `.container` element that prevented the dropdown menus from showing - not the `position: fixed`. By hiding overflow, you're preventing elements (such as your dropdown menu) that exceed the dimensions of the `.container` from displaying.

```css
.container {
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  background-color: rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.9);
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.container a {
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.container a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #ff008f;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.98);
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f9e9ff;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="stripes">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="contact-us.html" target="_top">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="products-gifts.html" target="_top">Products & 
Gifts</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Treatments</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="body-contouring.html" target="_top">Body 
Contouring</a>
        <a href="cellulite.html" target="_top">Cellulite</a>
        <a href="laser-hair-reduction.html" target="_top">Laser Hair Reduction</a>
        <a href="laser-peels.html" target="_top">Laser 
Peels</a>
        <a href="led.html" target="_top">LED</a>
        <a href="photofacial.html" target="_top>" Photofacial & Photobody</a>
          <a href="spider-veins.html" target="_top">Spider 
Veins</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="home.html" target="_top">Home</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that makes sense, and that was the only thing I neglected to change. Thanks for the help